# how to delete last two word in the sentences

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
alex\|facebook\|google\|amazon\|src\|cmd\|<last space avalible>
```

The above is the sentences in a file name test. I want to delete the last `\|` and extra space with shell scripting command. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

If by `<last space avalible>` you mean any combination of zero or more trailing spaces and horizontal tabs, you can use

```
sed 's/\\|[ \t]*$//'
```

Ex. given

```
$ echo 'alex\|facebook\|google\|amazon\|src\|cmd\|        ' | cat -A
alex\|facebook\|google\|amazon\|src\|cmd\| ^I $
```

(where `^I` indicates a tab between two spaces) then

```
$ echo 'alex\|facebook\|google\|amazon\|src\|cmd\|       ' | sed 's/\\|[ \t]*$//' | cat -A
alex\|facebook\|google\|amazon\|src\|cmd$
```